# Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT - Return to one column instead of two?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Using this formula returns values in two separate columns:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+)\?|(.+)\"""))`

How can I modify this to return everything in the same column? It works if I remove the parentheses (), but then the last character ? or " will appear at the end.

Comment: is this for domain extracting?

Comment: it looked suspicious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+)[?""]"))
```

The pattern matches

- `(.+)` - Group 1 (the group value is actually the return value here): one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `[?"]` - a `?` or `"` char.

Consider also the following variations:

```sql
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+?)[?""]"))
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "([^?""]+)[?""]"))
```

The `"(.+?)[?""]"` variation matches up to the first occurrence of `"` or `?`. The `"([^?""]+)[?""]"` also matches up to the first occurrence, but it can also match line break chars.